# change expo push notification icon

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

According to the docs I need a 96x96 gray transparent png. I have created this and put the following in my app.json file yet still I see the expo icon. Is there something I am missing?

```
"notification": {
  "icon": "http://example.com/pushIcon.png"
}
```

Code to send push notification

```
try {
    fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            to: messages.map((value, index) => value.pushToken),
            sound: "default",
            title: 'Notification title',
            body: "This is the body of the notification",
        }),
    });
} catch (err) {
    alert("Unable to send request, please try again later.");
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the icon and place in your project folder and link the path like this

```
 "notification": {
      "androidMode" : "default",
      "icon" : "./assets/pushIcon.png"
    }
```

Download from this link :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EEpzjoD_TONMU3Wt3NzL5nPWu1bFCs5O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but still the expo icon remains. Do you have an example png that you know works?

Comment: Yes I've, do you want to try with that?

Comment: Yes, could you please attach it here so I can download and try?

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it but still the Expo icon is showing up when I receive a push notification for some reason. I am going to update my question with my other code. Is there something maybe wrong in there?

Comment: restart with cleaning expo start -c

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate you trying to help, I just don't know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still having the same problem, try this
**for android**
Create apk using `expo build:android`
and use expo token in expo notification tool, to test icon.
**for ios**
Create build and release it on testflight to test app in real device.